# convert a hash of arrays in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a (big, over 850 entries) hash with keys like this:

```
{
  "asserts.regular" => 0,
  "asserts.warning" => 0,
  "asserts.msg" => 0,
  "asserts.user" => 0,
  "asserts.rollovers" => 0,
  "connections.current" => 29,
  "connections.available" => 51171,
  "connections.totalCreated" => 489,
  "metrics.commands.aggregate.failed" => 0,
  "metrics.commands.aggregate.total" => 2029,
  "metrics.commands.appendOplogNote.failed" => 0,
  "metrics.commands.appendOplogNote.total" => 0,
  "metrics.commands.applyOps.failed" => 0,
  "metrics.commands.applyOps.total" => 0,
  "metrics.commands.authSchemaUpgrade.failed" => 0,
  "metrics.commands.authSchemaUpgrade.total" => 0,
  "metrics.commands.authenticate.failed" => 0,
  "metrics.commands.authenticate.total"  =>0
}
```

the depth of the entries is dynamic.

I want to turn this into a hash like this (some keys omitted for brevity):

```
{
  asserts: {
     regular: 0,
     warning: 0,
     msg: 0
  },
  connections: {
    current: 29
  },
  metrics: {
    commands: {
      aggregate: {
        failed: 0
      },
      authenticate: {
        failed: 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried up till now ? Could you please post your current attempt at writing the code to resolve this

Comment: you don't need to be a pro to try something :)

Comment: before you stone me, I'm not a ruby pro! ;)
that's definitely above my horizon.

    h = {}
    input.each do |i|
        h = i.inject({}) { |m, e| m[e] = e; m }
    end

Comment: Some of the keys are missing from the result seemingly arbitrary. Is there some pattern here, or did you just simplify the result for the sake of brevity?

Comment: @BodoSchulz you can use backticks, i.e. `\`code\`` to post code in comments, but in order to clarify your question you should edit it instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }

hash.each do |key, value|
  *nesting, leaf = key.split('.').map(&:to_sym)
  result.dig(*nesting)[leaf] = value
end

result
```

The idea is:

1. Create an infinitely nested hash. Basically, whenever you search for a key not present, an empty hash will be associated to that key.
2. For each key, dig up to the penultimate subkey (result of splitting by `.`) and assign the value at the last subkey of the digged hash.

Answer (score 3):

```
h.each.with_object({}) { |(k, v), r|
  k.split('.').map(&:to_sym).tap { |*f, l|
    f.inject(r) { |t, p|
      t[p] ||= {}
    }[l] = v
  }
}
```

EDIT: A bit late, looking at ndn's answer, this is the same idea, just without `dig`, and in fully functional style...

Answer (score 0):

Just one more fun way to handle the problem

```
h.transform_keys{|k| k.split('.').map(&:intern)}.each_with_object({}) do |((*a,l),v),obj|
  a.reduce(obj) {|memo,k| memo[k] ||= {}}[l] = v 
end
# If ruby < 2.4
h.map { |k,v| [k.split('.').map(&:intern),v]}.each_with_object({}) do |((*a,l),v),obj|
  a.reduce(obj) {|memo,k| memo[k] ||= {}}[l] = v 
end
```